# Minitoc Doesn't appear in Report class

Tags: titlesec, report, minitoc

I'm trying to add `minitoc` as shown below. As far as I know (and written [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minitoc/minitoc.pdf) pg 416) `minitoc` doesn't work with `titlesec` but is there any way around?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,abstracton,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb,subfigure,mathrsfs,
    fancyvrb,booktabs,multirow,color,feynmp-auto,multicol,chngcntr,rotating,wrapfig,
    epsfig,scrpage2,graphicx,authblk}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}

\counterwithin{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus0.5ex minus0ex}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}  

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\newlength\rulew
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\filleft\sffamily\bfseries}
{\fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont\textcolor{LightSteelBlue3!80!}{\thechapter}\hskip2mm}{0em}
{\fontsize{25}{10}\bfseries\llap{\parbox[b]{0.7\linewidth}{\filleft#1\vskip-6ex}}\hskip2mm}%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20ex}



\cfoot{\pagemark}

\title{\Large Some title} 
\author{\textit{me} }
\affil{\textit{Supervisor:} sup}

\date{\normalsize place \\ \today}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}


        {\huge \bfseries  \@title }\\[10ex] 
        {\normalsize \@author}\\[20ex] 
        {\normalsize \@date}

    \end{center}


\end{titlepage}
\makeatother
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%\include{abstract}
%\include{acronyms}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

%\newpage


\newpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addstarredchapter{Introduction}

blalbqfklwehowue

\chapter{High Energy Physics: Where do we stand?}
\minitoc

\section{The Standard Model of Particle Physics}
%\ac{CMS}
\section{Problems with the Standard Model}

\section{Supersymmetry}




\begin{appendices}
%   \include{acronyms}
\end{appendices}




\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove `includegraphics` and `include` it should be compilable. I dont have any compilation problem

Comment: 90% of the packages in this `document` are not necessary to show the problem. Use `titlesec` (if really necessary) or `minitoc` but not both